# Multiple Socket Server using Spring Boot and Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to develop a TCP Socket server which listen on multiple ports and send specific messages to client based on port they connect . 
But when i created 3 TcpNetServerConnectionFactory and trying to start it on 3 port. 
It's throwing error **TcpNetServerConnectionFactory may only be used by one inbound adapter**

So my requirement is start the server to listen on 3 different ports and based on client connection send different messages. 
It must be achieve using Spring Boot and Spring Integration.

Comment: Can you show some code and identify the line giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to see a configuration for those 3 `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory`s and their usage, but that

> TcpNetServerConnectionFactory may only be used by one inbound adapter

Says that you use the same `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` instance in different adapters:

```
/**
 * Registers a TcpListener to receive messages after
 * the payload has been converted from the input data.
 * @param listener the TcpListener.
 */
public void registerListener(TcpListener listener) {
    Assert.isNull(this.listener, this.getClass().getName() +
            " may only be used by one inbound adapter");
    this.listener = listener;
}
```